# Can't import pyueye module, dll errors

Tags: python, camera, python-3.6, dllimport

I wanted to use pyueye module to manipulate my IDS camera. I've installed latest drivers from manufacturer's website and I can manage the camera by using uEye Cockpit appliaction. I wanted to write some python script to use with camera, but i can't even import pyueye module.

My code:

```
import ctypes
from pyueye import ueye
print(ueye.__version__)
```

Error info:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Users/Karol/PycharmProjects/ids_camera/ids_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyueye\dll.py", line 165, in load_dll
dll = DLL(libinfo, libnames, os.getenv(envname))
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyueye\dll.py", line 96, in __init__
raise RuntimeError("could not find any library for {} ({})".format(libinfo, 
dllmsg))
RuntimeError: could not find any library for ueye_api (DLL_PATH: unset)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 \File "C:/Users/Karol/PycharmProjects/ids_camera/ids_test.py", line 2, in 
<module>
     from pyueye import ueye
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyueye\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from . import ueye
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyueye\ueye.py", line 54, in <module>
    get_dll_file, _bind = load_dll("ueye_api", ["ueye_api_64", "ueye_api"], 
"PYUEYE_DLL_PATH")
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyueye\dll.py", line 167, in load_dll
    raise ImportError(exc)
ImportError: could not find any library for ueye_api (DLL_PATH: unset)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have installed that module via pip, my OS is Win 7 x64, my python interpreter is 3.6, also *.dll files associated with ueye are installed in C:\Windows... folder. I also copied ueye_api.dll and ueye_tools.dll files to pyueye directory, but it didn't help.

Comment: Well, after successfull pyueye module import with python 2.7 i tried once more with python 3. It worked, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `ueye_api_64.dll` from `C:\Program Files\IDS\uEye\USB driver package` to my `pyueye` folder. I also added this location to the system variable's PATH and this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

- Restart your computer after the installation.
- Make sure the DLL is in your C:\Windows\System32 directory.
- Set PYUEYE_DLL_PATH to the directory of where the DLL is located.

When nothing of that helps please contact the IDS support.

Answer (score 0):

I only put the DLL in the C:\Windows\System32 directory and it works right away. No restart, no addition to PATH.
Cheers.

(Python3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).